# Facebook Like button throwing an error and showing a duplicate

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

If you look at the homepage of http://beta.gulfdine.com/, you will note that the bottom bar has a Facebook "Like" button. I have used the code for this from the Facebook documentation page, and am loading the Javascript for this asynchronously, as follows:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: facebookAppId, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });

    //The below is used to expand the bottom section to display the sharing section on clicking 'like'
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
        openNewForm(function () { $("#shareFacebook").show("fast"); }, 'facebook');
    });


};
(function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
} ());
```

The button itself is simple FBML:

```
<fb:like layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="110" font="trebuchet ms"></fb:like>
```

All this was working fine until recently, and now a duplicate "Like" button is shown next to the normal one (the one with the 'x people' text). Firebug shows a Javascript error "ExternalPageLikeWidget is not defined" in the Facebook page that is called (http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php).

Does anybody have any experience with this error, or know what might be causing it? I'm completely bamboozled at this point. Can't tell if this is an FB bug, or something that I'm doing wrong.

Edit: It appears that the bug only shows when you have "Liked" the page. Please try doing so and refreshing the page. You can unlike the page once you've tested this out. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the button on the page you linked to. Just guessing here but you could double-check that the URL you've specified for your app in your Facebook app settings matches the URL of the page you've put the button code on.

Comment: Woah, really? That's strange! Which browser are you using? Could you please try and use another one and tell me if you still can't see it? The URL, etc. were working fine earlier, and I can still see the button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to the page http://beta.gulfdine.com/ and I see the Like button is working just fine. (it does not duplicate itself and shows the likes count correctly)

I'm on a mac with MacOS Snow Leopard and checked your site using opera 11.01 http://d.pr/oujH ,safari 5.0.3 http://d.pr/Y2zY and firefox 3.6.13 http://d.pr/SAjj (the links are screenshots of the browsers)

I hope it helps you figure what's wrong... maybe you can tell us in which browsers and OSs are you having problems

Comment: Hmm...that is indeed weird - I have tested on Chrome 9+, FF 3.6+ on Windows 7. I think it shows itself only when you check the page after clicking "Like" once (the Like state changes to show that you have liked it). Would you mind trying this out, please? You can unlike it once you have done so. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to like and unlike successfully using safari 5.0.3 (http://d.pr/Adtj), firefox 3.6.13, opera 11.01 and Chrome 9.0.597.102 (all of them in MacOS Snow Leopard 10.6.6). Once I liked the page, the status changes accordingly and a fb comment box (the one of fb like) is shown. Then I reloaded the page and the fb like button was still showing and working fine. (I've uploaded only 1 image because it was the same with all browsers). I also tryed in FF 3.6.13 on Windows Xp and it was also working fine, just like in the other browsers.

Comment: I think FB has just changed the way the "Like" button is shown now. When I initially implemented the code, the "Like" button in gray wasn't displayed. I thought this was a bug, but I guess not. Thanks for testing across browsers!